# .htaccess RewriteRule not working - nothing happens

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got my site setup and i've got a news system. On my old hoster it worked and now I changed my hoster and it dont work anymore.

Basically: https://www.xxabcxx.com/news.php?newsid=1 to
https://www.xxabcxx.com/news/1

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /news.php?newsid=$1 [L]
```

I'm only getting a white site with no code.

I already tried to view the `GET` via

```php
print_r($GET);
```

It only shows `Array ()`.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: can you please tell me the hosting name ?

Comment: Where i host my Webserver?